# Eclipse creates too many (millions) of local history files?

Tags: eclipse, rad

My Eclipse environment continually creates local history files, and I cannot figure out why. Over the course of a month, I end up with several million files in .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history

Almost all of them are small files, copies of some MANIFEST.MF. All are the same.

I am using RAD 7.5, with the m2eclipse plugin (maven), and ClearCase. I use the following setup:

Project | Build Automatically is turned off
Preferences | Workspace | Local History is set to keep only 1 history version, and to keep the file for only 1 day.

I had one project alive for several months, and there were more than 20 million local history files created. This many little files is a serious problem for Windows -- I even got a blue screen when I attempted to delete them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem with the projects that seem to be continually creating these history files. Each project that had this problem contained an empty configuration file

```
org.eclipse.wst.common.component
```

Actually, the file was not quite empty. It's contents looked like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0"/>
```

Since these projects are all JSF projects, the component file should look something like this. I manually editted the file (in MyWebApp/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component), restarted Eclipse, and immediately noticed that the system was much faster, and history files were no longer being created.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
  <wb-module deploy-name="MyWebApp">
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="WebContent"/>
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/java"/>
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/resources"/>
    <property name="context-root" value=".MyWebApp"/>
    <property name="java-output-path" value="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <property name="jsf.base" value="7.5.0.0"/>
    ... the above property (I think) is RAD specific
    ... many more property elements with name="jsf.*" 
  </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```

If you use maven, you have to be careful with the *source-path* attributes. The default by maven is probably "/src/main/webapp", but for my project (and in the above configuration), I needed the Eclipse default of "WebContent" (Sometimes the default is "Web Content").

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the majority of those files are created as a result of ClearCase actions.  If you checkin, checkout, merge, etc every day then you may have that many new files created daily on your behalf.  Since the history is compacted only when you exit RAD/Eclipse, you might never see those files go away.

Start and shutdown your workspace on a Monday morning after a weekend (of doing no work in RAD :).  Hopefully ClearCase won't jump in and do something automatically on your behalf.  If after shutdown those files are gone then your problem is tied to the daily use of ClearCase (or most any version control plugin)

Comment: These files are created continuously, at a rate of two or three per second. I don't really think it's the result of ClearCase actions, because the files get created even if I have not logged in to ClearCase. Also, they are all the same file, an empty MANIFEST.MF

Comment: Weird.  My only suggestion at this point is to create a new workspace and import each project from your original project one at a time.  Leave the projects in place (don't copy files) and after each project import check to see if the empty files are being created in the new workspace's history.  If you find that importing a particular project starts the problem then that would give you an idea of which tool/plugin is going crazy.  If the problem hasn't occurred after you've imported all of the projects then just use the new workspace.

Comment: I have done that (create a new workspace) several times. I have similar projects (all are JSF apps, all use Hibernate and Spring, nearly identical in terms of achitecture) where this does not occur. I'm pretty sure the problem is because of maven. I have found a file in the workspace -- a version of MANIFEST.MF that is output by the maven build -- where the creation timestamp is continuously updated. So I guess maven is recreating this file, and it goes into Eclipse local history.